# The JLabel not showing in my code

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jlabel

**how to display the jlabel text**

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("number adition");
JButton button1  = new JButton("add");

button1.setBounds(110, 250, 70, 20);
frame.add(button1);

frame.setSize(500, 400);
frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setVisible(true);

JButton button2  = new JButton("Clear");

button2.setBounds(210, 250, 70, 20);
frame.add(button2);

JButton button3  = new JButton("Exit");

button3.setBounds(210, 280, 70, 20);
frame.add(button3);

JLabel label1= new JLabel("First", JLabel.NORTH_EAST);
label1.setAlignmentX(0);
label1.setAlignmentY(0);
frame.add(label1);
```

Comment: As with all questions related to this subject, `frame.setVisible(true);` should be called last AFTER you have established the UI.  Otherwise you need to call `revalidate` and `repaint`, but since you've thrown away the layout manager, `revalidate` will have no effect

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Answer (score 1):

In null layout each component needs to be sized. Because of you are not setting bounds to the label, it is not displaying.

By the way, using null layout is a very bad practice. I suggest you to learn how to use layout managers and pick the most suitable one for your case. [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)